# is it possible to show the alert message on top of another sharing dialog

Tags: objective-c, alert, presentviewcontroller

Im using this code to try and show a alert message on the iphone

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

it works fine.

But is it possible to show the alert message on top of another sharing dialog also shown using presentViewController:

at the moment it shows a warning in the console and the alert does not show, only shows the popup for the sharing activity?

I can get this to work using UIAlertView  but that deprecated now

Comment: please post the full text of the warning shown in the console

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, it would be good to include the text of the warning you're receiving in the question as well.

My guess is it's along the lines of:

> Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fe676036000>  on <ViewController: 0x7fe674e02f50> which is already presenting <UIActivityViewController: 0x7fe67580f800>

Which basically indicates you can't present another view controller using a view controller that's *already* presenting a separate view controller.

One way you could work around this is to climb the presentedViewControllers to locate a view controller which isn't already presenting and then present from that (in your case you should only need to move up one presentedViewController to your UIActivityViewController).

Here's an example using the `UIWindowScene` to grab the rootViewController (iOS 13+), but should basically be the same idea for using the appDelegate's window as well:

```
- (IBAction)showShareSheetAndAlert:(id)sender {
    UIImage *homerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Homer"];
    UIActivityViewController *shareSheet = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[homerImage] applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:shareSheet animated:YES completion:^{
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test Alert" message:@"Here's a test alert on top of a share sheet" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *dismissAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Dismiss" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alert addAction:dismissAction];
        UIWindowScene *windowScene = (UIWindowScene *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] connectedScenes] allObjects] firstObject];
        UIViewController *viewControllerToPresentOn = windowScene.windows.firstObject.rootViewController;
        // keep climbing the presented view controllers until we find the top one which isn't presenting
        while (viewControllerToPresentOn.presentedViewController != nil) {
            viewControllerToPresentOn = viewControllerToPresentOn.presentedViewController;
        }
        [viewControllerToPresentOn presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Which will result in this:

[image: Share_Sheet_Alert_Example]